Web scraping error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
Why is there an AttributeError, but my code can scrape from the web.
My code:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.28hse.com/estate/detail/mei-foo-sun-chuen-2520/transaction"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
quotes_divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='item')
    
for quote_div in quotes_divs:
    quote = quote_div.find( class_='content').text       
    print(quote)

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\dennis li\.spyder-py3\untitled0.py:13
    quote = quote_div.find( class_='content').text

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'


Did you even expend time debuging how looks quote_div

It means that the method .find() didn't find what you're looking for (using class_ = "content"). Hence it returns None. In the end, ".text" can't be applied to None so it triggers an error.
So either you can wrap your function in a if statement :
quote = quote_div.find( class_='content')
if quote is not None:
   content = quote.text
   print(content)
else:
   print("No content found here")

